# HiveServer2 - Not starting / working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I've installed Hadoop 2.7.2 and Hive 2.0.1 on local Ubuntu local VM. Hive is working fine on the shell and able to create tables & load data. The problem is with the hiveserver which I want to retrieve data from clients as well as load data from Java program.

When I try to start HiveServer2 nothing is happening as following.

**hadoop_user@ubuntu:~$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hiveserver2**

I checked in hive-site.xml and all configurations seem to be fine.

Any idea what is going on? Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "nothing is happening". Also check `netstat -ntpl | grep 10000`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The moment I run the following .....
hadoop_user@ubuntu:~$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hiveserver2

it goes to the next line and stays there. I am suppose to get the message "Starting Hive Server"........I am not getting that and not sure the service is started and I checked the Hive Server Web UI and it's down. I am sure something is missing in the configuration or any install component is missing... Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you do a few checks, `netstat -ntpl | grep 10000` see if this command returns anything. And also check whether the Hive metastore is started and running?

Comment: Here it is.
hadoop_user@ubuntu:~$ netstat -ntpl | grep 10000
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

I believe Hive metastore should be running since I am able to run Hive queries from the Hive shell. Not sure what's happening with Hiveserver2 which is driving me crazy.

Comment: Can you update the post with `hive-site.xml`

Comment: Is it possible to attach a file here?

Comment: No, you can copy the properties from the file and edit them in the question as code.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you fix this? I read other posts that it can be a Namenode issue.